# Server response OK (200) but no file uploaded to server

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am trying to upload a text file generated in a app to a server.
When trying to get the server response I get a exception  EOF thrown.

Any input appreciated

My create file code:

```
File sdCard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File theDirectory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            theFile = new File(theDirectory, "userdetails.txt");
            theDirectory.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            //file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            out.append(username+"\n");
            out.append(email+"\n");
            out.append(password+"\n");
            out.close();
```

...
uploadFileName = theFile.toString();
uploadFile( uploadFileName);

Upload Method:

```
String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       Log.d("REGISTRATION PAGE", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="
                                             + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }



                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.d("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                //messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         // messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode;
```

And my php script on server:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

UPDATE:
Changed the DataOutPutStrem args here(I had a \ in the world place):

```
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

This gives a server

> `response =  OK and respoonseCode = 200;`

However I see no new file in the server directory!
Ive Logged the directory where the new file should be as the URL+filePath which is

> www.mooneycallans/Rotunda//storage/emulated/0/userdetails.txt

But should this not read:

> www.mooneycallans/Rotunda/userdetails.txt

...
as userdetails.txt is the name of the file I have created in the app.

Comment: Witch catch is reporting an eof exception? Logcat please. Is the file correctly uploaded?

Comment: Get a EOF exception thrown at the first try block where trying to get server response: // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

Comment: I checked the File size (int length-theFile.lenght())=287 so i believe the file is not empty

Comment: The server  response is 'Internal Server Error: 500'

Comment: The file is not empty on your device. But what is its size on the server? You have more ways to check if the content is the same on your device and the server.

Comment: looking at the directory on the server i docent see a file os created

Comment: Shouldn't you write a Content-Length too. flush() your dos before reading the response.

Comment: So you received a response code (which one?) And a response message (which one exactly?) And still there was a catch? What was e.getMessage() and in which catch?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. My php scrip was the culprit, I had the path as :

```
$file_path = "uploads";
```

Instaed of:

```
$file_path = "uploads/";
```

A day and a half later but it works :)